# Building an example project with Tycho issues an error

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, rcp, tycho

Trying to build a Tycho configuration cloned from an example from Vogella (https://github.com/vogellacompany/tycho-example) I got an error during materialize-prodcuts phase:

```
[INFO] --- tycho-p2-director-plugin:2.2.0:materialize-products (materialize-prodcuts) @ com.portlab.test.product ---
[WARNING] Error injecting: org.eclipse.tycho.plugins.p2.director.DirectorMojo
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/tycho/BuildDirectory
```

Then I created own configuration just like the Vogella example, and got same error.

Comment: According to the log, nothing is like in the Vogella Tycho example: a different Tycho version fails to build a different product. Both, the Vogella example and the current Tycho version work for me.

Comment: Sorry, log is from my test designed just like Vogella's. In Vogella example I got the same error. 
So I should change Tycho version to 2.0.0?

Comment: The latest version is 2.2.0. Make sure to use everywhere the same version, also in `.mvn\extensions.xml` ([I do it this way](https://github.com/howlger/IDEalized/blob/b0f339fa7b9d93474309abb0d4ce0dc0b8949352/pom.xml#L11-L15)).

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. Version info was missing in original example for tycho-p2-director-plugin. You need to add to pom.xml in com.vogella.tycho.configuration:

```
             <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
                <artifactId>tycho-p2-director-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${tycho.version}</version>
            </plugin>
```